# Selenium Webdriver C# How to verify if an element and it's value which is a dynamic text is already visible?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How to verify if an element and it's value which is a dynamic text is already visible using Selenium Webdriver C#?

Comment: Could you share which have you tried so far?? And relevant HTML as well

Comment: I tried below code but my assert command always resulted to False.

`var CustomerID = waitExp.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span[contains(@data-bind,'text: CustomerId')]")));
string CustomerValue = CustomerID.Text;
Assert.IsNotNull(CustomerValue);`

The CustomerID generates dynamic text. My first assumption is that my code gets the value of the CustomerID even the system does not generate the dynamic text. That's why when I assert, it does not get any value and fails.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm making some assumptions here about things your question isn't very specific on. I'm assuming the element is any kind of html tag and the "dynamic?" text you refer to is its' inner text.

From the top of my head:

```
Boolean visible = false;
IWebElement element = Driver.GetElement(By.Xpath(expression));

if (element is IWebElement && element.IsDisplayed())
{
    if (element.Text == expectedText) 
    {
        visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it generates dynamic text.